# Proxy support via ChromeOptions on Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\xxxx\\IdeaProjects\\chromedriver.exe\\");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("107.175.153.215:3128");

options.setCapability("proxy", proxy);

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.get("https://www.ipinfo.io");
```

I've been trying to figure out why this isn't working. I've also tried with geckodriver, and haven't had any success. It used to be fine a year ago, so not sure as to what's wrong/different.

I see this being iterated in the console for a bit, and then it stops.:

```
[1582009560.815][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were close. Since [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) v3.6.0, the `ChromeOptions` class in [java](/questions/tagged/java) client also implements the `Capabilities` interface, allowing you to specify other [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) **capabilities** not specific to ChromeDriver. So may you need to:

- Instead of using the `ChromeDriver` class, use the `WebDriver` interface.
- Additionally, you need to remove the trailing escaped back slash i.e. `\\` from the `chromedriver.exe` path.
- Your effective code block will be:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\xxxx\\IdeaProjects\\chromedriver.exe");
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
  proxy.setHttpProxy("107.175.153.215:3128");
  options.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
  ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://www.ipinfo.io");
  ```